# I'm getting this error when I generate a new rails application

Tags: ruby, ssl

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for rubygems.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for ruby gem.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Could not verify the SSL certificate for rubygems.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without
using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

I ran `gem update --system`, but it did not work. I came down with another error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

What is going on here and how can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: Try [these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error).

Comment: Hi Sirajus!  Thank you for the help.  I used the non-ssl version of rubygems in my gemfile as a temporary fix.  I changed the gem sources like so in terminal: gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/
    gem sources --add http://rubygems.org
    gem update --system   and these steps temporarily fixed the problem because when I tried to generate a new rails application, I have the same SSL certificate issue.  Why is this happening?  How can I permanently fix the problem?  Does this have anything to do with the way how I installed ruby?

Comment: Hi @user5622933, wish I could be of more help, but I am also new on ruby on rails, so my knowledge is very limited.  I installed ror on my ubuntu following [these steps from GoRails](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04) without any hassle, you can chek it out if you like.

Answer (score 1):

This issue usually occurs with old versions of rubygem.
You can try updating it by running

```
gem update --system --source http://rubygems.org/
```

and after that

```
gem update
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error).

Comment: But this step would temporarily fix the problem because when I try to generate an application I am seeing the same SSL certificate issue error.  Do I need to install a newer version of ruby?  Thank you

Comment: @user5622933, what version are you using currently? and how did you install?

Comment: I'm using: ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0].  I used Ruby Version Manager to install ruby.  Shall I uninstall ruby and re install it's newer version?

Comment: @user5622933, thats really not a solution, but I am out of ideas too. If its not a hassle or if you're in a hurry you can reinstall. Follow [this guide](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04) for help. To uninstall rvm follow [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679422/after-i-use-rvm-implode-to-uninstall-rvm-its-still-fully-functional)

Comment: If uninstalling ruby and reinstalling it won't solve the SSL certificate problem than I don't need to do that right now.  I'm still wondering why do I have this problem with SSL certificate every time I create a new rails project. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Create a new file `.gemrc` in your home directory and add this line.

```
:ssl_verify_mode: 0
```

Now, it should continue even if it can't verify that the SSL connection is "trusted".